# How accept a friend request using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, api

With this query i get udi of the users requesting a friendship.

```
getIstance().executeFqlQuery("select uid_from from friend_request where uid_to=me()", JsonObject.class);
```

But once get the udis how can i accept this requests using the restfb API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook API does not allow accepting friend requests.

Perhaps you can have a look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/).